# Mysterious disappearing static IP address on wifi interface under Debian?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, wifi-hotspot

With these lines in `\etc\network\interfaces`...

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.8.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.1
```

... the interface comes up about 10 seconds after boot and `ifconfig` shows the interface with correct static IP address...

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:b5:06:18
          inet addr:192.168.8.1  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

...but about 10 seconds after that, the static IP address disappears...

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:b5:06:18
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

What is going on here and how can I configure this interface so that the static IP is permanent?

(I am running Linux version 3.8.13-bone72 on a Beagle Bone Black)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `wicd` daemon, which runs by default in this distribution.

Apparently, `wicd` was waking up a few seconds after the normal ifup/down scripts had configured the interface and blindly re-configuring it to use DHCP.

This was very hard to track down.

The solution is to disable the `wicd` daemon from running at bootup with the command...

```
service wicd disable
```

Once this is done, the Wifi interface will continue to work as configured in `interfaces`.

However, in this distribution the `wicd` apparently also handles the `eth0` interface by default so it will no longer come up automatically on reboot.

You can fix this by adding the lines...

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

...to `/etc/networking/interfaces` to allow the normal ifup/down scripts to also bring up and manage `eth0`..